# Mathematica automaticly evaluates some cells

Tags: manipulate, evaluation

Is there a command or a trick to tell Mathematica to not automaticly evaluate some cells?

I use the `NMinimize` function to calculates some coordinates and then use that data with `Manipulate`. When I run `NMinimize`, Mathematica automaticly runs `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Manipulate` is based on `Dynamic`, so if output of `Manipulate` is already created, then it will dynamically update every time when related variables have changes.

If you want to stop such behavior of Mathematica, you need to stop dynamic update temporary. And Start it again when it is needed.
You can do it through GUI or by usual Mathematica command `FinishDynamic[]`

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your description correction you want to restrict `TrackedSymbols` to only those directly controlled by `Manipulate`.  This means that when a non-tracked Symbol definition is modified the `Manipulate` will be "out of date" until you move a slider, etc.

```
fn = Sin;

Manipulate[Plot[fn[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
```

[image]

Now when you update `fn` nothing should change:

```
fn = Tan;
```

[image]

But then when you move the `a` slider:

[image]